# How to make a tail-recursive method that can also refer to itself in a non-tail-recursive way

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

Suppose I have a mechanism for long-running computations that can suspend themselves to be resumed later:

```
sealed trait LongRunning[+R];
case class Result[+R](result: R) extends LongRunning[R];
case class Suspend[+R](cont: () => LongRunning[R]) extends LongRunning[R];
```

The simplest way how to run them is

```
@annotation.tailrec
def repeat[R](body: LongRunning[R]): R =
  body match {
    case Result(r)   => r
    case Suspend(c)  => {
      // perhaps do some other processing here
      println("Continuing suspended computation");
      repeat(c());
    }
  }
```

The problem is creating such computations. Let's say we want to implement tail-recursive factorial that suspends its computation every 10 cycles:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def factorial(n: Int, acc: BigInt): LongRunning[BigInt] = {
  if (n <= 1)
    Result(acc);
  else if (n % 10 == 0)
    Suspend(() => factorial(n - 1, acc * n))
  else
    factorial(n - 1, acc * n)
}
```

But this does not compile:

> error: could not optimize `@tailrec` annotated method `factorial`: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
>
> ```
> Suspend(() => factorial(n - 1, acc * n))
> ```

How to retain tail recursion on the non-suspending calls?

Comment: Just FYI: `LongRunning` is the partiality monad!

Comment: @MyseriousDan Thanks, that's very interesting. Actually, `LongRunning` is a simplification of my original problem - I'm working on a [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit)-like library for Scala [scala-conduit](https://github.com/ppetr/scala-conduit) where `Pipe` naturally forms a monad.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of thing is generally an instantiation of a free monad of some sort. The partiality one is a little odd because it's generally represented as a corecursive thunk, but whether you have `Free[() => _, R]` or `Free[ChunkOfData => _, R]` makes little fundamental difference.

Comment: Note also that this actually already exist in the standard library: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one possible answer. We can move the tail-recursive part into an inner function, and refer to the outer one, non-tail-recursive, when we need:

```
def factorial(n: Int, acc: BigInt): LongRunning[BigInt] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def f(n: Int, acc: BigInt): LongRunning[BigInt] =
    if (n <= 1)
      Result(acc);
    else if (n % 10 == 0)
      Suspend(() => factorial(n - 1, acc * n))
    else
      f(n - 1, acc * n)
  f(n, acc)
}
```

Comment: Am I right saying that this going to re-create closure *instance* on every `factorial` call?

Comment: @om-nom-nom I'm not really sure how well Scala optimizes such closures. Anyway, they're created only for suspensions, which don't occur too often. (This example is a bit simplified.) But I can say from my observations that the memory footprint stays constant. I tested another similar computation that used 1000000 suspensions. It ran very fast, consuming only a very little memory.

Comment: "Am I right saying that this going to re-create closure instance on every factorial call": No, a closure is only created when suspending. When `f` calls itself, the call is indeed tail recursive and thus there is no further stack use (hence no stack overflow).